# Facebook SDK 3.2 for iOS share description more than three line is not appear

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-sharer

I shared the description to facebook by using facebook sdk 3.2. 
If the description is more than three lines then remaining description is not appear in web but in mobile app even description is not visible.
So is there any way to set read more option.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. My client's app which is in app store also have same issue. Any way we can see share content while sharing post.

Facebook mobile app and web browser have some limitation to see `description` which have post via app. They have some parameters must to be shown in post like picture, link, caption, name.
Sample parameter to be sent in post:

```
params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"I'm using the Test iOS app", @"name",
        @"Test for iOS.", @"caption",
        @"Check out Test iOS to learn how you can make your iOS apps social using Facebook Platform.", @"description",
        @"http://m.facebook.com/apps/uniquenamespace/?deeplink=news", @"link",
        @"http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png", @"picture",
        @"foo", @"ref",
        nil];
```

If the description field have more character means, they discard those content webserver.
But in mobile app, they discard entire description , if parameter have name field.
But in safary, little bit different. They may be differ from browser by browser also..

Comment: thanks mani, in this description my content get differ for each post. Then how can we show the entire description.